# How to Detect right mouse down and other mouse down while left mouse dragged on NSTextView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I'm trying to achieve invoke action when user select text with left mouse and holding left mouse button and click right mouse `btn`.

I'm currently override `rightMouseDown` and `otherMouseDown`, but it does not called while user holding left mouse `btn`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Why would a user right click while still holding left mouse down? This isn't even possible with most Mac hardware. Wouldn't it be enough if the user selects text, releases left mouse & then right clicks again?

Answer (score 2):

Why would a user right click while still holding left mouse down? This isn't even possible with most Mac hardware. Wouldn't it be enough if the user selects text, releases left mouse & then right clicks again?

But in case you *really* need such a feature: 
I have not tested this, as I have not the hardware for simultaneously call left & right mouse down, but it *might* work.

You can go a level deeper and work with `CGEvent` objects. 
Here is how they work:

Create a bit mask to define the events you want to respond to.

```
let eventMask = eventMask | (1 << CGEventType.leftMouseDown.rawValue)
                          | (1 << CGEventType.leftMouseUp.rawValue)
                          | (1 << CGEventType.rightMouseDown.rawValue)
                          | (1 << CGEventType.rightMouseUp.rawValue)
                          | (1 << CGEventType.otherMouseDown.rawValue)
                          | (1 << CGEventType.otherMouseUp.rawValue)

self.eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: .cghidEventTap, place: .headInsertEventTap, options: .defaultTap, eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask), callback: { (proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent, userInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? in
        // mySelf is self, if you need to refer to objects in this class
        let mySelf = Unmanaged<MyClass>.fromOpaque(userInfo!).takeUnretainedValue()

        if type == .leftMouseDown || type == .leftMouseUp {
            // Left mouse down etc..

        }

        return Unmanaged.passUnretained(event)
    }, userInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()))
```

And finally you need to add this returned `CFMachPort` to a runLoop.

```
let runloopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0)
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runloopSource, CFRunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

That's it!. Try it, I am curious if it works.